# How can I escape a double quotation mark in VisualForce context?

Tags: visualforce, html, string, text

I am trying to process a string before displaying it in a visualforce page. What I need to do is remove any quotation marks in the text field before I use it to assemble a link path. The following code works - it removes any 'S' characters from the string. However when I substitute in a '"' which is what I want to remove, it is interpreted as ending the value argument and the page won't save. I thought I could escape it out with '\"' or '\\"' and I also tried '&quot' but none of those options worked.

```
        <td class="value">
            <apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Work_Order__c.Drawing_Path__c, 'S', '')}" />
        </td>
```

I know that I could do my processing at another step (either with a formula field or an apex trigger) but I was really hoping to do it here as I have other areas built around the string still having the quotes in it. Is there any way to solve this problem in the VisualForce page only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in my developer org:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Account.Name,'\"','')}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apparently, syntax highlighting can't seem to figure it out, but it should compile just fine (press Enter in the demo page to see the resulting output).

Comment: So it is! I feel pretty silly for just being thrown off by the syntax highlighting. With tho backslashes I got an actual error in the 'problems' section about the expression being unbalanced, but if I let it update, it goes away with one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a controller?

```
public static String parseString(String theString, String checkFor, String replaceWith)
{
    String result;

    result = thestring.replaceAll(checkFor, replaceWith);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am using the standard controller, but I see how if I switched to a custom one that would work.

Comment: How is this any different than simply calling replaceAll directly on the original string, without a particularly verbose function call?

Comment: @sfdcfox, I'm not sure why I did it.. I think I had a reason, but I forget why now

Comment: If I hard coded the " in the apex, rather than taking checkFor as an argument, then it would have solved the problem since I know how to escape things in apex.